# 'Series' object has no attribute 'len' Panda CSV file

Tags: python, pandas

I want to print based on column that contain number of characters. In that specific column contains different length of string. My current codes as follows;

```
  if df['UDH'].len(8):
    df=df.groupby(df[['UDH'].str[:7],'Original Sender ID','Received Date/Time'])['Body'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
    if df['UDH'].len(9):
        df=df.groupby(df[['UDH'].str[:8],'Original Sender ID','Received Date/Time'])['Body'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
        if df['UDH'].len(10):
            df=df.groupby(df[['UDH'].str[:9],'Original Sender ID','Received Date/Time'])['Body'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
            if df['UDH'].len(11):
                df=df.groupby(df[['UDH'].str[:10],'Original Sender ID','Received Date/Time'])['Body'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
                if df['UDH'].len(12):
                    df=df.groupby(df[['UDH'].str[:11],'Original Sender ID','Received Date/Time'])['Body'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
```

My csv file contain column Body, Received Date/Time, Original Sender ID, and UDH.

Now UDH is the primary key. The way to concatenate the Body is to groupby received date/time, original sender ID and UDH. However, UDH some of it are only 8 character long and some of them are 12 character long.

Comment: The error message is extremely clear: there is no `Series` method called `len`. Hence your problem with expressions like `df['UDH'].len(8)`. What are you trying to accomplish by writing `len` here?

Comment: Hi @ApproachingDarknessFish, thanks for get into my problem. I'm quite new to pandas. The UDH column contains different values with different number of string, the minimum number of characters is 8 and the highest is 12. Did I do something wrong with the len or should it be .str.len(8)?

Comment: There does exist a method `DataFrame.str.len`, but it takes no arguments. `df['UDH'].str.len()` will give you a series containing the number of characters in each string in the column `df['UDH']`.

Comment: Are you trying to select the rows in `df` where the column `'UDH'` has a certain number of characters in it?

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish yup, that’s exactly what I’m looking for. Would you mind write an example for me?

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish is this how I should write it:

if pd.DataFrame.str.len(df) == 8: 

Correct me if I'm wrong, much appreciated

Comment: Getting closer, but that will still not work. I'm typing up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems that need to be addressed here. The easier one is how to check the lengths of strings in a column. The correct syntax is `df['UDH'].str.len() == 8`. However, this comparison does not return a simple `bool` value that we can use with an `if` statement: it returns a *series* of `bool`s, telling us whether the string length was 8 or not for *every* element in the column. `if` statements are the wrong tool to use because of this.

Instead, we can split up the dataframe into subsets of rows by using the boolean series as an index. This will return a dataframe containing only the rows of `df` where `df['UDH']` is equal to 8:

```
rows_of_length_8 = df[df['UDH'].str.len() == 8]
```

Also note that there is no need to repeat the same logic so many times. You can use a loop:

```
for i in range(8, 12+1):
    rows_of_length_i = df[df['UDH'].str.len() == i]
```

And use `i-1` as your slice argument in the groupby.

Comment: I've tried like this, is it correct?

      df_i = df.groupby(df[df_i - 1, 'Original Sender ID', 'Received Date/Time'])['Body'].apply(''.join).reset_index()

I'm really sorry for hassling you, I'm very new to python and pandas, hence a bit slow at this

Comment: @SyafiqRosli It might be difficult to tell exactly without some more information on the program and the relevant variables.

Comment: @AMC updated about my csv files and intended result

Comment: @approchingDarknessFish appreciate if could give your feedback.